# updated correct chrome driver path/driver version and add selenium jar too, but still getting below issue , could you help me for this?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

code :

```
package Demo1;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class Chrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
  WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtmeQOcdIKI");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    }

}

error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:847)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at Demo1.Chrome.main(Chrome.java:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the system property too late.

Looking at the stacktrace, the exception is being thrown while executing the following line of your code:

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
```

At that point, the line of your code that sets the system property hasn't been reached yet.

Evidently, you need to set the system property **before** creating the `ChromeDriver` object.

Answer (score 0):

The first line in your main method should be :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
```

something like this.

```
public class Chrome {

  WebDriver driver = null;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
     driver = new ChromeDriver();
     driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtmeQOcdIKI");
     System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    }

}
```

should get the job done.